How to constrain lines within a shape, using Adobe Illustrator
I have two shapes: a set of pink lines and a black shape. I want the pink lines to fit neatly inside the black shape. I've attached two images to show what I'm aiming for. Aligning these shapes manually, especially for complex ones, can be very time-consuming. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient solution for this.



Hi. There's no way to do this automatically in Illustrator AFAIK, if that is what you are asking.  The closest I've found is to this is something available in Inkscape. It has a Hatches (rough) Path Effect than can do something similar automatically, if you tweak the settings, although it's not perfectly regular.

I can't think of any automated way to get a similar rigid structure constrained by another shape in Illustrator. Scribble just creates loops, not the straight paths with curved connectors. In fact, I can't think of a way if it were just simple rectangles (which you could round afterwards. Everything I come up with would be an equal amount of effort to just manually tweaking the paths.

All manual work here, until Adobe introduces AI for these things :)

Been trying different approaches. All of them ended up involving manual work. Perhaps the best was to rasterize the shape, turn it into Object Mosaic, delete unneeded lines, join and round the corners.
